# How to secure backend SQL calls from Bubble.io front end?

Tags: postgresql, bubble.io

I am using a `Bubble.io` SQL connector plugin to make stored procedure calls from a backend PostGres DB (Public access is ON).

I wanted to know how to secure these calls, assuming I turnoff public access and setup private subnet for the DB.

Right now , the only option i see is `ssl=true` option.

Comment: Sal is a encrypted connection, so if you trust bubble , you are as secure as bubble is